# Details on the telescope(s) on the Chinese Space Station 天和

Tags: space-telescope, iss, csst

The [ISS has a telescope](https://www.universetoday.com/99470/space-station-gets-a-new-telescope/) on board. Does the [Chinese Space Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong_space_station) have one on board as well?

I heard about [Xuntian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuntian) aka Chinese Space Station Telescope (CSST), but not too many details. Would that be the only telescope? What would be the primary scientific goals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chinese Space Station (CSS) has many instruments. It is [planned](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.13992) to conduct a spectroscopic survey of hundreds of millions of galaxies. The Chinese Space Station Optical Survey (CSS-OS) is a planned full sky survey with applications to, e.g., [cosmology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04634) and [photometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09586). It will "probe weak and strong gravitational lensing, galaxy clustering, individual galaxies and galaxy clusters, active galactic nuclei..." This effort has been in the works for over a decade, e.g., [here](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011SSPMA..41.1441Z/abstract). There are also many laboratory [experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong_space_station#Experiments) planned.

The CSS is the culmination of the [Tiangong program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong_program), which began in 1992, and this is why it's known as the [Tiangong Space Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong_space_station). The word "tiangong" means "heavenly palace."

[Xuntian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuntian) is a planned telescope that will co-orbit the CSS for periodic docking. It is expected to have a much larger field of view than the Hubble Space Telescope, and may rival the James Webb Telescope.

Keep in mind that the efficacy of Chinese cooperation with international science programs is [controversial](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.08618).

Comment: [Should a few more users vote to accept the csst tag wiki and excerpt quickly to ensure that nobody else follows my lead and rejects them?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/750/7982)

Comment: How do I vote for that initiative?

Comment: There is something called review queues, lists of various things (mostly edits and close votes) that users review to see if they agree or disagree. Participation in each queue is based on reputation points; the more reputation one has, it is assumed that the more experience one has with how the site works and how the community works and so the "better" one will vote properly in the reviews.  I don't know about mobile devices but in my laptop browser I first click here https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1iou.png and then I see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/YltEj.png

Comment: You might not see most of them since your reputation is currently low. I can tell that you really contribute well to the site so I'm sure your rep will increase quickly :-) In the main Stack Exchange meta there is a [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) and you can look up many topics like [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080) and [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/303080)

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you ;)